# Pointer to object with vector memory leak

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, destructor, memory-leaks

I seem to have a little memory leak problem with vectors.
My code looks like this:

```
    class CPart {
    public:
        virtual void print() = 0;
    };

    //some other classes

    class CDisk : public CPart {
    public:
        CDisk(int tp, int size);
        ~CDisk();
        virtual void print();
        void AddPartition(int size, const string & dsc);

        static const int MAGNETIC = 0;
        static const int SDD = 1;
    private:

        struct CPartition {
            CPartition(int size, const string & dsc);
            int div_size;
            string disk;
        };
        int type;
        int d_size;
        vector<CPartition> ptts;
    };

    CDisk::CDisk(int tp, int size) {
        type = tp;
        d_size = size;
    }

    CDisk::CPartition::CPartition(int size, const string& dsc) {
        div_size = size;
        disk = dsc;
    }

    void CDisk::AddPartition(int size, const string& dsc) {
        ptts.push_back(CPartition(size, dsc));
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        CDisk disk(CDisk::SDD, 5000);
        disk.AddPartition(500, "disk1");
        CPart *disk2 = new CDisk(disk);
        delete disk2;
        return 0;
    }
```

When I run this code with valgrind, it says there are memory leaks and the number of bytes lost is equal to the number of items in vector ptts * size of CPartition. So I am guessing I have to clean that vector somehow. I have tried that but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have [virutal destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors/461224#461224) in CPart

```
 class CPart {
    public:
        virtual void print() = 0;
        virtual ~CPart(){};
    };
```

Otherwise you will get following scenario;

```
  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        CDisk disk(CDisk::SDD, 5000);
        disk.AddPartition(500, "disk1");
        CPart *disk2 = new CDisk(disk);//CDisk created
        delete disk2;//But here only CPart is deleted leaving CDisks data in memory
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use valgrind to very precisely isolate the origin of memory leaks by using additional leak check parameters, ie:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

As long as your code is compiled with debug symbols, valgrind will tell you exactly where the leak is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this part is really true;

```
struct CPartition {
    CPartition(int size, const string & dsc);
     int div_size;
     string disk;
};

CDisk::CPartition::CPartition(int size, const string& dsc) {
    div_size = size;
    disk = dsc;
}
```

It is better to put `struct CPartition` out of your class definition and get rid of `CDisk::CPartition::CPartition(int size, const string& dsc)` i.e:

```
struct CPartition {
     int div_size;
     string disk;
};
```

To call `div_size` of an instance of `CPartition` you should do

```
instance_of_CPartition->div_size
```

For further, read [structure tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/).

I'm not sure if this will solve your question but this will solve another problem in your code.